# Looping through a dataset, comparing values to another dataset

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two datasets. One(DFlogin) contains a set of user ids, and two digit "zip codes" they attempted to log in from. The other(Dfrecords) contains a list of acceptable "zip codes" for the user to log in from.

For a user, they could have any number of attempted log in zip codes, and any number of acceptable, record zip codes.

The goal is to loop through the rows of the DFlogin dataset, and compare each users attempted logins to all of the acceptable logins for the specific user.

So user 1 can login in zipcode 34 only, but has logged in from zip code 21. This user should be flagged in a new column (bad_login).

```
userid<-c(1:3)
zipcode1<-c(21,23,4)
zipcode2<-c(NA, 34, 32)

DFlogin<-data.frame(userid,zipcode1,zipcode2)

recordzipcode1<-c(34,23,42)
recordzipcode2<-c(NA, 34, 32)
recordzipcode3<-c(NA, 21,61)

DFrecords<-data.frame(userid, recordzipcode1,recordzipcode2, recordzipcode3)
```

I would guess the solution could work with a couple loops and an if statement, but I am not really sure where to start.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: final expected output is the DFlogin table, having an additional column, "bad_login" it would get a 1 if the login zipcodes dont match on of the acceptable zip codes

Comment: this way i could have a final table of just exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `apply` row-wise on `DFlogin`.

Find the matching `ID` in `DFrecords` table. Select only the columns that have zip code values (`2:4`). Remove the `NA` values. Check if all the values i.e logins are from the acceptable zip codes.

```
DFlogin$bad_login <- apply(DFlogin, 1, function(x)  {
      x1 = DFrecords[match(x[1], DFrecords$userid),2:4] 
#2:4 are the columns having zipcodes in DFrecords
      y = x1[!is.na(x1)]
      as.integer(!all(x[2:3] %in% y))
#2:3 are the columns having zipcodes in DFlogin
})

#[1] 1 0 1
```

Comment: can this solution be generalized to any number possible zip codes per user? One user could have one zip code , and some could have a 10 acceptable zip codes

Comment: yep..should work for all. The only change you need to do would be selecting columns which have zip codes in it. I have updated the answer with comments.